# Shortcut to execute .jar in command line (terminal)

Tags: java, terminal

I have written a program in Java that one can use via the Terminal CLI. I've packaged it in a .jar, and it works nicely, however it happens to be a tool that I'd like to use quite often via CLI.

I am familiar with executing .jar files using:

```
java -jar MyJarFile.jar
```

but I'd like to be able to run this using a single command.

The only way I've done something similar to this is by using an NSTask object in Obj-C (my skills in C/C++ are limited), but this is a slightly different situation.

The solution might be staring me in the face, and might be quite simple, but any help to find a different method for launching my .jar would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could write a shell script or place a "short cut" into the ".profile" or ".bash" or what ever that file is :P - See the section [Making Your Own Shorthand](http://lifehacker.com/5743814/become-a-command-line-ninja-with-these-time-saving-shortcuts)

Comment: The easiest way would be to simply use an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell script would work too.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar MyJarFile.jar
```

save this as RunMyJarFile.sh and give it execute permissions.

```
./RunMyJarFile.sh
```

is all you need to do.

Comment: I just ended up using a shell script. It'll work fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Launch4J or other java wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an alias to your .bashrc like this:

```
echo "alias mycmd=\"java -jar MyJarFile.jar\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

then source it (or reopen the terminal) with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

now you can just type `mycmd`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of choices:

- Just click on the Jar from the GUI - on most (all?) platforms, double-clicking on executable Jars will run them.  If that works for your use case, that's the easiest thing to do.
- Just put your `java -jar ...` call into a shell script; put it on your `PATH` if you want.  Quick and easy, but it requires keeping track of both the shell script and the Jar file, which might end up being a case of "now you have two problems".
- Use a [wrapper utility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/147181/113632) to convert your Jar into a binary or `.exe` installer.  These will bundle your Jar with a script or binary that will unpack and run your Jar automatically for you.  It's been a couple years, but I've used [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) to create an .exe installer pretty painlessly.